# EXCEL: How to copy a range of cells in new sheet and have the range changing automatically

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets named (Supplier1, Supplier2) which they have 20 rows, and 3 columns (SKU,PRICE,AVAILABILITY). I want to copy columns SKU, AVAILABILITY to a different main sheet BUT if I add new rows later in Supplier1 or Supplier2, main sheet to be automatically updated

I tried so far the

```
VLOOKUP($A3;INDIRECT(C$2&"!$A2:F50");6;FALSE)
```

Can the cell of indirect F50 to change whenever I add rows?

is this possible?

Comment: I'm confused on why you are using `INDIRECT` , but if you must then try a combination with `COUNTA`.

Comment: Ι Check the SKU which is located in Main Sheet and get the values from the others

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53883497/edit) to provide sample data and expected outcome? I see no reason why a straightforward `VLOOKUP` wouldn't do the job you describe